# Can I set a property to be equal to a function inside the body of a constructor function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out if (other than the obvious fact that in one case the value the of following constructor function is set to the name of a function outside of the constructors braces and in the other case the value is set directly to the function itself, inside the function) these two codes are any different in any significant way.

```
function people(name, age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.yearsUntilRetire = yearsLeft;
}

function yearsLeft(){
  var numYears = 65 - this.age;
  return numYears;
}
var natalie = new people("Natalie Portman", 28);
var joony = new people("Joony  Boony", 24);
```

and...this code?

```
function people(name, age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.yearsUntilRetire = function(){
        var numYears = 65 - this.age;
        return numYears;
  }
}


var natalie = new people("Natalie Portman", 28);
var joony = new people("Joony  Boony", 24);
```

Now, I've noticed that both codes work, for my purposes, *exactly* the same.  I just wanted to know if there is any difference between the two codes or if they are, exactly the same.  I prefer the tighter code, where the function is nested inside of the constructor rather than all loose outside of the function, but I've seen several tutorials that set the value to a function outside of the constructor function (as in the first example).  This is kind of puzzling to me because it seems more logical to create a blueprint for an object all in one self contained space rather than all over the place where you have to scan up and down to find what this refers to, and where.

I guess my ultimate question is whether one way is right and the other is wrong, or whether one has advantages and the other doesn't.  Is there a "normal" way to do this or is it just a free for all and the programmer should just do whatever they want?

Comment: The first code "leaks" `yearsLeft` to the parent scope, whereas the second may (depending on browser's implementation - read "probably") create a separate function object for each instance of `people` which leads to slightly greater memory consumption.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol If an implementation did not create a separate function object in the second example then it would be a very bad implementation.  That kind of optimization is not possible in JavaScript, since you don't know if maybe later someone is going to store a property on the function object or compare them to each other (in which case them being the same object would result in incorrect behavior).

Comment: @cdhowie Right, but it could be a lazy copy. I don't know. I'm not a low-level enough programmer to know. For all I know, it could be like PHP's `$a = [1,2,3]; $b = $a;` - here there is only one array - `$b[1] = 4;` and now there are two in memory.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Ah, you are talking about copy-on-write.  I missed that.  In that case there would be many flyweights pointing at a template function object.  Yes, that could be a valid optimization.  As long as from the JavaScript side they all appear to behave as separate objects, there would be no issue.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll note this.

Comment: @cdhowie—there's not much point in arguing over implementation detail unless you're talking about a specific implementation and know how it works internally. There are various ways to implement "one function per instance" so that it *appears* that way but may or may not be. It's the apearance that matters, not the implementation.

Comment: @RobG We are not arguing anymore.  :)  We were initially because it sounded like he was saying that an implementation might optimize such that all function objects would appear to be the same object from the JS side of things, which would be an error.

Answer (score 2):

The differences are:

- **Scope**: In the first case, `yearsLeft` doesn't have access to local variables defined inside `people`. In the second case it does.
- **Visibility**: In the first case the function is defined and accessible outside of `person`.
- **Memory**: In the second case, every invocation of `person` will create a new inner function. I.e. for two instances of `person`, `p1.yearsLeft === p2.yearsLeft` will be `false` which might be surprising.

The correct way is to define shared properties on the **prototype**:

```
function People(name, age){
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

People.prototype.yearsLeft = function() {
  var numYears = 65 - this.age;
  return numYears;
};
```

If you want to learn more about OOP in JavaScript, I recommend to read the [MDN article about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Comment: I'm learning the prototype method right now, I just wanted to clear up some of the other ways of doing things just for reference purposes.  Thank you.  I'll incorporate your example as a reference, I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: A good post about functions and prototype usage http://freshbrewedcode.com/jimcowart/2013/02/12/getting-into-context-binds/

Comment: Those MDN articles are soooooo dry, it's very hard to read.  It's tough for newbies to start out because every question leads to 50 other questions, and it becomes impossible to get to bottom of anything if every question leads to yet another question.  Sometimes you just need a human to explain something to you otherwise one can tend to get lost in programming jargon.

Answer (score 1):

The second example will create a new function object for each separate object (if an implementation optimizes this away they are making a *serious* mistake) while the first example pollutes the global namespace with a function.

Aside from Felix's approach of using the prototype (+1 to him), you can also use an immediately-executed closure to hide the function:

```
var people = (function () {
    function yearsLeft(){
        var numYears = 65 - this.age;
        return numYears;
    }

    return function (name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.yearsUntilRetire = yearsLeft;
    }
}());
```

The function object returned from the outer function gets assigned to the `people` variable, and it has access to the `yearsLeft` function defined in the outer function.  Code outside of this function has no access to `yearsLeft` (except, of course, through the `yearsUntilRetire` property of objects created from this function).

While this may not be the best approach for this particular problem (prototypes are a bit cleaner in this case) this technique of immediately-invoking a function that returns another function is a very powerful way to create a function that depends on private data.